# How to control the checkbox using the Python itself, and not by a mouse click?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I created a checkbox using PyQT, which normally works using mouse clicks.

I want to know if there is a way with which I can uncheck and check the checkbox using the program itself, and not a mouse click.
Basically I want to check and uncheck the box 10 times in 20 seconds and display it happening.

Here is my code for just the checkbox:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 40))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Checkbox") 

        self.b = QCheckBox("Yes",self)
        
        self.b.move(20,20)
        self.b.resize(320,40)

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **checked** : bool
>
> This property holds whether the button is checked
> Only checkable buttons can be checked. By default, the button is unchecked.

The **QTimer** class provides repetitive and single-shot timers.
More ... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QCheckBox, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class ExampleWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(140, 40))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Checkbox") 

        self.b = QCheckBox("Yes",self)
        
        self.b.move(20,20)
        self.b.resize(320,40)
        
        self.num = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(2000)                 # msec
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_now)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_now(self):
        self.b.setChecked(not self.b.isChecked())               # +++
        self.num += 1
        if self.num == 10: self.timer.stop()

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = ExampleWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

[image]